# Simple socket server that can send raw messages that I type in?

Tags: sockets, putty

Does a simple socket server exists that sends any message I want to send to all clients? I need to do this to test a socket client. And FAFAIK Putty can't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but maybe have a look at netcat (there are ports for nearly any platform just search for netcat).

For an overview of netcat's functions look at [the man page of it](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=nc).

Answer (score 1):

you can use "telnet portno" if its a tcp socket